# Python 3's http.server.HTTPServer has a one second delay on localhost

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I've got a client and a server running on the same box. The client is able to issue `urllib.request.Request()` commands to external URLs and get responses back in about 0.1 seconds, fast enough that as a user I'm not noticing any real delay. When issuing a `Request()` to my local `http.server.HTTPServer()` there's a 1 second delay between the client calling `urllib.request.urlopen()` and the server's `do_GET(self)` even getting the request.

I saw some answers suggest that it was an issue with DNS lookup for logging, and that overwriting `address_string(self)` would fix it, but I'm still seeing the exact same delay with or without the modification.

Server:

```
import http.server
import time

class MyHTTPHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler): 
    def do_GET(self):
        start = time.time()
        print(start)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def address_string(self):
        host, port = self.client_address[:2]
        return host  

server = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', 9999), MyHTTPHandler)
try:
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopping server')
```

Client:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import time

def send_data():
    start = time.time()
    r = urllib.request.Request(url='http://localhost:9999')
    print(time.time())
    urllib.request.urlopen(r)
    print(time.time() - start)

while True:
    input('Press enter to send')
    send_data()
```

Any ideas what I'm missing to get rid of that one second delay? I'd like this basic server to respond at least as fast as a web server would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks like this might be a problem with Python versions.

Running Python 3.5.2 for Windows I get the 1 second delay.
Running Python 3.4.3 for Ubuntu (technically Ubuntu for Windows) I get no delay.

Answer (score 4):

It might seem strange, but try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in your client.

Comment: I was having the same issue on Windows 10, version 1809. 
Both a python flask server and a native application were responding over `localhost` with 5, 150 or 300ms delays (quite sequentially in that order). Switching it to `127.0.0.1` brought it down to a consistent 5ms